# table = new HashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE]

Tags: c++, hashtable

I am learning about hash tables and came across the following line of code with weird syntax

```
table = new HashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE];
```

Can somebody explain to me what this syntax means?
I don't understand why there is a '*' before the square brackets?
You can check the full code containing this code line here: http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Hash_table/Simple_example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's allocating array of pointers to `HashEntry`

Answer (score 1):

It allocates an array of pointers.

```
table = new HashEntry[TABLE_SIZE]
```

is an array of `HashEntry` objects.

```
table = new HashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE]
```

is an array of `HashEntry` pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It's an array, of size TABLE_SIZE, whose elements are pointers to HashEntry.